# Cannot join LivePatch Service due to "snap not found" error

Tags: canonical-livepatch

...when I run

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
```

to install it, I get the error message "Snap not found." My architecture is 16.04 LTS (32-bit). Please advise.

Comment: What ubuntu version you use ?

Comment: 16.04 LTS (32-bit).

Answer (score 4):

The canonical-livepatch service and snap are currently only available in 64bit, which is why snapd can't find a i386 snap.

You can see the supported architectures for a snap on its snap store page https://uappexplorer.com/app/canonical-livepatch.canonical

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install snapd` will fix this :)
After that you can run the snap install command

Comment: I've had snapd installed for a while now; it doesn't help. I still get "Snap not found."

Comment: I've since upgraded to a 64-bit system and am now successfully running the canonical-livepatch service.